# Elementor - updating query before render_element()

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am trying to set up a dynamic filter for posts widget in Elementor using Ajax.
What is an equivalent of Wordpress `query_posts()` for Elementor posts widget before running:

```
$posts_widget_html = $document->render_element($posts_widget);
```

which returns posts belonging to current query?

Comment: You'll probably want to use Elementor's [Custom Query Filter](https://developers.elementor.com/docs/hooks/custom-query-filter/) for this.

Comment: @disinfor custom query filter allows to use  it directly in elementor editor, specifying its id in query settings.

Comment: Yes, I know how it works. You'll need some way to target Elementor's query to do what you want. So add a query id to the posts widget, and now you have a way to target the actual query.

Comment: @disinfor ok i will try that tommorow.

Comment: @disinfor I am struggling with this. Can't do any step towards a solution. Would You be so kind providing any tips? Best regards

Comment: How are you trying to setup a filter? Please provide the code you are trying to use to filter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257161/discussion-between-kuba-m-and-disinfor).

Comment: @disinfor I texted You in the chat above

Comment: @disinfor I did rewrite exactly the same as in ajax_render_widget() function from Widgets_Manager class. query_posts() function doesn't affect the global $post variable for the updated render. What am I doing wrong?